# Why can't I call an instance method from another module to initialize a lambda in ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

I am trying to refactor an existing code to simplify.  Originally I was calling the module methods like a static utility method in java.

Here is the new code:

```
module Module1
  def mod1() 1; end
end

module Module2
  include Module1
  def mod2
    puts mod1()
    puts 2
  end
  Constant = lambda { mod1() }  # This line fails
end

class Sample
  include Module2
  def go
    mod2
    Constant.call  #  <module:Module2>': undefined method `mod1' for Module2:Module (NoMethodError)
  end
end

Sample.new.go
```

I can make it work if a simply duplicate the code in `Module1` into `Module2`.  Is there a better solution?

Edit: Additionally, I should be able to call methods in `Module1` from classes that directly include it.  For example:

```
class Sample2
  include Module1
  def go
    puts mod1()
  end
end
Sample2.new.go
```

**Actual module 1:**

```
module HtmlUtils
  def wrap(tag = :span, class_names, text)
    %(<#{ tag } class="#{ class_names }">#{ text }</#{ tag }>)
  end
end
```

**Actual module 2** The problem is the duplicated code in the 3rd from the last code.  It can be replaced by the HtmlUtils#wrap method.

```
module Markdown
  include HtmlUtils
  BOLD = {
    regexp: /(_{2}|\*{2})(.*?)\1/,
    lambda: ->(token, regexp) { "<b>#{ token[regexp, 2] }</b>" }
  }
  NUMBER = {               
    regexp: /(?<=\s|\()[+-]?(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+)?(?!-|\.|\d|,\d)/,
    lambda: ->(token, regexp) { %(<span class="num">#{ token }</span>) }  # Redundant Code
  }
end
```

**Client1 includes Markdown, and in effect HtmlUtils.**

```
@parser.regexter('bold', BOLD[:regexp], BOLD[:lambda]);
@parser.regexter('numbers', NUMBER[:regexp], NUMBER[:lambda])
puts @parser.parse('some **string** 1')  # => some <b>string</b> <span class="num">1</span>
```

**Client2 includes HtmlUtils**

```
@parser.regexter('quote', /(?<=)((["']).*?\2)/, ->(token, regexp) { wrap(:quote, token));
puts @parser.parse('s="Hello"')  # => s=<span class="quote">"Hello"</span>
```

Comment: `Sample::Constant` isn't aware of the instance created via `Sample.new`. Let's say you have two instances, `s1 = Sample.new` and `s2 = Sample.new`. Which `mod1` should be invoked via `Sample::Constant.call`?

Comment: In my requirement, I don't need a specific instance of `mod1`. It should return the same for every instance, although it has parameters in actual to make the distinction.  Forgive my ignorance but are you suggesting that I should  stay with using module method?

Comment: I'm not sure. Why do you want to assign a proc / lamda to a constant in the first place? `Sample::Constant.call` looks odd to me.

Comment: I placed the actual code.  I needed to make the regex and the function to stay together that is why I made it in to a constant that holds a hash.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** Attempt to answer original question (before the actual code was posted).

Well, it depends. If the modules ship everything they need themselves, you could make `mod1` a module-function and call it explicitely (then no need to include the module). But I fear that you actually need the context.

```
module Module1
  def self.mod1() 1; end
end

module Module2
  def mod2
    puts Module1.mod1()
    puts 2
  end
  Constant = lambda { puts Module1.mod1() }  
end

class Sample
  include Module2
  def go
    mod2
    Constant.call  
  end
end

Sample.new.go
```

outputs

```
#=>
1
2
1
```

Otherwise you could unconstantize the lambda:

```
module Module1
  def mod1() inmod2 ; end
end

module Module2
  include Module1

  def inmod2
    1
  end

  def mod2
    puts mod1()
    puts 2
  end
  def constant
    lambda { puts self.mod1() }
  end
end

class Sample
  include Module2
  def go
    mod2
    constant.call
  end
end

Sample.new.go
```

Which works (same output). Unfortunately, I cannot explain you why. Am happy to read a answer that includes explanation (feel free to copy my code).

Comment: The first one would work but then classes that directly include `Module1` would have to fully qualify to access `Module1` methods, which is a little similar to the original.  The second one doesn't work for the same scenario.  Sorry if I did not mention that `Module1` can be included directly by other classes. I'll update the question.

Comment: @JohnDoe Why does the second one does not work? `Module1` can be included and methods can be called from/of it.

Comment: I get this error: `undefined local variable or method `inmod2' for #<Sample2` Sample2 includes module 1, and calls the `mod1()` method.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thats because that example should illustrate a case where the module is included and uses data from the including class (namely the inmod2() method). Change the definition of `Module1#mod1` to be self-contained if you want.

Comment: You are right it works.  However, when I change the definition of `NUMBER` constant to a `def`, it will require changes to all client calls.  I have to weigh in, if it's worth changing everything to method for uniformity, along with the client calls.  Thank you @Felix for giving me an option.

Comment: I remember there are languages that requires constants to be initialized by literals and not with calculated values, that could be the case in in my problem as well.